# Window not detecting key input when changing datacontext

Tags: wpf, vb.net, xaml

Window xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="wndVerkoopOrderInvoer"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:Delivery_Manager.DeliveryManager.ViewModel"
xmlns:vw="clr-namespace:Delivery_Manager.DeliveryManager.View"
xmlns:st="clr-namespace:Delivery_Manager.Settings;assembly=Delivery_Manager_Settings"
xmlns:sf="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Surface.Presentation.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Surface.Presentation"
Title="Bestel" Height="526" Width="1063"
WindowStyle="None" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" ResizeMode="NoResize">
<Window.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="..\ResourceDictionaries\resdictMain.xaml" />
</Window.Resources>
<Grid PreviewKeyDown="cc1_PreviewKeyDown">
    <ContentControl Grid.ZIndex="2" Name="cc1" Content="{Binding VMFullScreen}">
        <ContentControl.Resources>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:VMVerkoopTakeaway}">
                <vw:ucVerkoopTakeaway/>
            </DataTemplate>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:VMFullScreenVerkoop}">
                <vw:ucVerkoopOrderInvoer/>
            </DataTemplate>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:VMFullScreenPayment}">
                <vw:ucVerkoopKlantBetaalMethode/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ContentControl.Resources>
    </ContentControl>
</Grid>
```

code behind:

```
    Private Sub cc1_PreviewKeyDown(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.Input.KeyEventArgs)
    Try

        If e.Key = Key.F12 Then

            If TypeOf (Me.cc1.DataContext) Is VMVerkoop Then
                Dim vm As VMVerkoop = Me.cc1.DataContext

                If TypeOf (vm.VMFullScreen) Is VMVerkoopTakeaway Then
                    Dim vmv As VMVerkoopTakeaway = vm.VMFullScreen
                    If vmv Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

                    If vmv.VMVerkoop.CanBetalen() Then
                        vmv.VMVerkoop.BetalenCommand.Execute(Nothing)
                    End If
                ElseIf TypeOf (vm.VMFullScreen) Is VMFullScreenPayment Then
                    Dim vmv As VMFullScreenPayment = vm.VMFullScreen
                    If vmv Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

                    If vmv.CanBetalen() Then
                        vmv.BetalingCommand.Execute(Nothing)
                    End If
                End If

            End If
        End If

    Catch ex As Exception
        WriteErrorLog("wndVerkoopOrderInvoer", "cc1_PreviewKeyDown", ex)
    End Try
End Sub
```

This window is initiated with the usercontrol called ucVerkoopTakeaway and his viewmodel and every time i press a key on my keyboard the subroutine will run correctly, but when the datacontext of the window changes (i.e: i load one of the others usercontrol into the window) i cant make the subroutine to run.. Do i need to do something on the window.DataContextChanged?? Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks you

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved, instead of using the `PreviewKeyDown` on the the grid i used it on the window it self by calling key `Keyboard.PreviewKeyDown="cc1_PreviewKeyDown"` after `ResizeMode="NoResize"`.